# Pointers inside shared memory segment

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I've been trying this for hours, and google all the things I kind think of, but I'm going crazy.

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  int rows;
  int collumns;
  int* mat;
  char* IDs_row;
} mem;
```

I don't know the sizes of the int* (a Matrix) and char* untill later.

When I do, I create the shared memory like this:

```
mem *ctrl;
int size = (2 + ((i-1)*num_cons))*sizeof(int) + i*26*sizeof(char); //I have the real size now
shmemid = shmget(KEY, size, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (shmemid < 0) {
    perror("Ha fallado la creacion de la memoria compartida.");
    exit(1);
}
ctrl = (mem *)shmat(shmemid, 0, 0);
if (ctrl <= (mem *)(0)) {
    perror("Ha fallado el acceso a memoria compartida");
    exit(2);
}
```

No problem here. Then I give a value to ctrl->rows and collumns, and assign 0 to all the matrix.

But after that, I write something in the char* and bam, segmentation fault.

Debugging the program I saw that both pointers, mat and IDs_row where null. How do I give them the correct values inside the shared memory segment??

I tried removing the char* pointer, just to give it a try, and then the segmentation fault error was in the other program that connected to said shared memory and just checked the values inside the matrix (checking ->rows and ->collumns was succesfull)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ctrl = (mem *)shmat(shmemid, 0, 0);
```

This only assigns valid memory to the `ctrl` pointer, not to `ctrl->mat` or `ctrl->IDs_row`.

You probably want:

```
mem *ctrl;
shmemid = shmget(KEY, sizeof(ctrl), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
//allocate memory for the structure
ctrl = (mem *)shmat(shmemid, 0, 0);

//allocate memory for the int*
shmemid = shmget(KEY,((i-1)*num_cons))*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
ctrl->mat = (int*)shmat(shmemid, 0, 0);

//allocate memory for the char*
shmemid = shmget(KEY,i*26*sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
ctrl->IDs_row = (char*)shmat(shmemid,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd never thought of doing the shmget for each pointer. (I don't even understand how that works, doing the same call but "casting" it)

Now there is a problem with the second integer in the struct, the "collumns". I put a "1" there in one process, and the other process reads it as 62045 or something like that. I tried changing sizeof(ctrl) to sizeof(men) and 2*sizeof(int)+sizeof(int*)+sizeof(char*), but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, i sent the message and then edited it. Can you help me a bit more? I have a problem now with the second integer in the struct.

Comment: @user1420534 please post a new question with this new issue, they don't seem related.

Comment: `ctrl` is a pointer. Using `sizeof(ctrl)` in the first call to `shmget()` is incorrect, although shared memory blocks always consist of integer number of pages and thus the size is rounded up to a multiple of the page size (at least 4 KiB on x86). Using the same value of `KEY` three times is also incorrect in that particular case - both `mat` and `IDs_row` field will point to the beginning of the same block and writing to any of them will overwrite the structure.

Comment: @HristoIliev I didn't know that. Haven't really worked with this stuff. But the principle stands.

Comment: The principle is that one should not put pointers in shared memory at all.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, putting *absolute* pointers in shared memory segments is **terrible terible idea** - those pointers would only be valid in the process that filled in their values. Shared memory segments are **not guaranteed** to attach at the same virtual address in every process. On the contrary - they attach where the system deems it possible when `shmaddr == NULL` is specified on call to `shmat()`. You could specify the same virtual address when calling `shmat()` but it is up to you to ensure that nothing else is mapped on that memory region in **all** participating processes. This is hard to do in a portable manner. What you would most like to do is to either:

1) Allocate one big shared memory segment that accomodates both the `mem` structure and the two data arrays. Then you should put not absolute pointers but rather pointers relative to the beginning of the memory block and then adjust on usage.

2) Allocate three different shared memory segments but instead of putting *pointers*, put the *shared memory IDs* as returned by `shmget()`:

```
typedef struct {
  int rows;
  int collumns;
  int mat_id;
  int IDs_row_id;
} mem;
```

When you need to access the matrix or the IDs array just attach to the shared memory ID stored in the corresponding field.

Pay attention though that using the same `KEY` in subsequent invocations of `shmget()` will not produce the expected result unless `KEY == IPC_PRIVATE`. It is best to use a the fixed key value for the shared memory block with the descriptor (of type `mem`) and `IPC_PRIVATE` for the other two memory blocks otherwise the three calls will actually return the *same* shared memory block - the first one will create it and the next two will simply return its ID since a block with that key already exists.