# Unix - Shared Memory

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory

I'm working with shared memory and I need several pointers for my program, but I have the restriction to use only one identifier:

```
int idSh;
int * mem;
char * mem2;

idSh = Shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof (char *) + sizeof (int *), IPC_CREAT | 0700);
mem = Shmat (idSh,0,0);
mem2 = Shmat (idSh,0,0);
```

I have to use several pointers with Shmat but I only have one segment of shared Memory with the identifier idSh.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you trying to share pointers between processes?  I don't think that's going to be useful, you can't guarantee that the address values are valid in another process.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776762/pointers-inside-shared-memory-segment?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to share pointers between processes, the identifiers are global.

Comment: Global identifiers are still unique to a process, pointers to them are also unique to a process.  You should not store pointers in a shared area.  If it appears to work then that is a coincidence which is not guaranteed.

Comment: If you want to share arrays then you should allocate the memory for those arrays inside the shared segment and copy contents to them - you will obviously need to synchronise that using something like semaphores.

Comment: From the Linux man page for `shmat`:  *Using shmat() with shmaddr equal to NULL is the preferred, portable
       way of attaching a shared memory segment.  Be aware that the shared
       memory segment attached in this way may be attached at different
       addresses in different processes.  Therefore, any pointers maintained
       within the shared memory must be made relative (typically to the
       starting address of the segment), rather than absolute.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite your ‘pointer based’ data structures to be ‘offset based’, and make a sort of directory at the beginning of your shared memory object.  The directory should identify the offsets to the root data structures, so each accessor can adapt to whichever address it is mapped at.   The bad news is that it is a lot of fiddly work; the good news is it usually makes source bases better.   Offset based has all sorts of advantages, such as being able to take a snapshot of the whole data structure, and write utilities that can analyze it off line.

Offset Based:  if you had a node in a linked list like:

```
struct Node {
     MyType Data;
     struct Node *Link;
}
```

you would need to change it to something like:

```
struct Node {
     MyType Data;
     uintptr_t Link;
}
```

Then walking your data structure looks something like:

```
extern uintptr_t ShmemBase;
struct Node *Next = (struct Node *)(ShmemBase + Cur->Link);
```

although I bet you could do a much better job of encapsulating this, maybe even associated the “Link” field with the particular shared memory object.

I’ve done these transformations in the past, and they typically aren’t as bad as you might imagine.   You do develop an appreciation for people who hide the data structure access methods properly....

Alternately, systems can often be coerced into mapping objects at a unified address for all participants; so if you hack around with your target system for a bit, you might find these magic addresses.  Eventually, somebody will hate you if you go this route.